# Filtering large number of rows based on timestamp

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a table that contains 8 million records on which I need to perform actions such as DELETE and SELECT based on field that is called `connect_timestamp` and has type of TIMESTAMP. The table is called `data`.

However doing something like

> SELECT count(*) FROM `data` WHERE unix_timestamp(`connect_timestamp`)
>   < 1483272827

Takes a very long time and causes services such as NGINX to timeout, is there a better way todo it with the built in MySQl functions for such a large amount of data?

I presume this is due to unix_timestamp() function, however doing a DATE_SUB
 isn't helping either

The column does have an index applied to it.

Comment: which datatype is the connect_timestamp colum?

Comment: TIMESTAMP is the type

Comment: Instead of calling a function on connect_timestamp, can you convert 1483272827 to a timestamp using FROM_UNIXTIME?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM data WHERE  connect_timestamp  < FROM_UNIXTIME(1483272827)
```

Comment: This seems to of given the best results, with query time just above 1 second

Answer (score 0):

A way for improve performace is avoid convertion type on columns (that implies a not optimal use of index by query optimizer and or the recorse of data table for filtering).. so you should use a where condition without conversion

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM data WHERE connect_timestamp < '2017-03-03 10:10:10'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting the timestamp before you put it in the query and then compare directly to connect_timestamp

```
SELECT count(*) FROM data WHERE connect_timestamp < '2017-01-01 12:13:00'
```

Also this gets count of all the data from before the first january, if the bulk of the data is here it has to go through all of those rows anyways

Comment: Thank you, however FROM_UNIXTIME() seems to of be doing the job 3 times quicker.

Comment: Probably something else led to the 3x difference.